# C++ Template class Inheritance, how to member type specification?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

```
template <typename _datTy>   
class ANode{
typedef ANode<_datTy> _nodeTy;
public:
    std::vector<_nodeTy> childVector;
};

template <typename _datTy, class _nodeTy = ANode>
 ATree
{
public :
    void doSomeThing()
    {
        auto iter = _root.childVector.begin();
    }
protected:
    _nodeTy _root;
};




template <typename _datTy>
class BNode :
    public ANode<_datTy>
{
typedef BNode<_datTy> _nodeTy;
public:
    bool somethingExtends;
};
template <typename _datTy>
 BTree :
    public ATree<_datTy, BNode<_datTy>>
{
 ...
};


BTree<char> test;
test.doSomeThing();
```

This code problem is `std::vector<_nodeTy> childVector`.
It's translate to `std::vector<Anode<_datTy>>` on BTree compile time.

But I really want this, 
`std::vector<Anode<_datTy>>` on ATree compile time, and
`std::vector<Bnode<_datTy>>` on BTree compile time.

I don't use base class pointer like this `std::vector<_nodeTy *>`,  on current architecture point.

how to any idea this problem?
Thanks for your read.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Something along these lines:

```
template <typename NodeType>   
class XNode{
public:
    std::vector<NodeType> childVector;
};

template <typename DataType>   
class ANode : public XNode<ANode<DataType>> {};

template <typename DataType>   
class BNode : public XNode<BNode<DataType>> {};
```

Comment: thanks your answer! I try to apply that pattern.